# Different strings with headstream and promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I use in my project a function:

```
function readStream(file) {

    console.log("starte lesen");

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.setEncoding('utf8');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = "";

        readStream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
        readStream.on("end", () => {resolve(data);});
        readStream.on("error", error => reject(error));
    });
}
```

It will read an xml file with around 800 lines in. If I add:

```
readStream.on("end", () => {console.log(data); resolve(data);});
```

Then the xml data is complete. Everything is fine. But if I call now this `readStream` from another function:

```
const dpath = path.resolve(__basedir, 'tests/downloads', 'test.xml');
let xml = await readStream(dpath);
console.log(xml);
```

then the XML data is cut. I think 800 lines is nothing big. So what can happen that the data is cut at this position but not in the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it like following way, it seems working for me.

For complete running example clone [node-cheat xml-streamer](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/stackoverflow_answers/xml-streamer/main.js#L5) and run `node main.js`.

*xml-streamer.js*:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.readStream = function (file) {
    console.log("read stream started");
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.setEncoding('utf8');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = "";
        readStream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
        readStream.on("end", () => {console.log(data); resolve(data);});
        readStream.on("error", error => reject(error));
    });
}
```

*main.js*:

```
const path = require('path');
const _streamer = require('./xml-streamer');

async function main() {
    const xml = await _streamer.readStream( path.resolve(__dirname, 'files', 'test.xml'));
    console.log(xml);
}

main();
```

P.S. In above mentioned node-cheat test xml file has **1121** lines.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes sync + async code can get a race condition when it's called in the same tick. Try using `setImmediate(resolve, data)` on your event handler, which will resolve on the next process tick.

Alternatively, if you're targeting node v12 or higher you can use the [stream async iterator](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator) interface, which will be much cleaner for your code:

```js
async function readStream(file) {

    console.log("starte lesen");

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.setEncoding('utf8');

    let data = "";
    for await (const chunk of readStream) {
        out += chunk;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happens to use a modern version of node, there's `fs.promises`

```
const { promises: fs } = require('fs')

;(async function main() {
    console.log(await fs.readFile('./input.txt', 'utf-8'));
})()
```